# Prove $\det(A - nI_n) = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Problem:** Prove that $\det(A - n I_n) = 0$ when $A$ is the $(n \times n)$-matrix with all components equal to $1$.

**Attempt at solution:** I tried to use Laplace expansion but that didn't work. I see the matrix will be of the form \begin{align*} \begin{pmatrix} 1-n & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 1-n & \cdots & 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1-n \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} I want to somehow get two equal rows or columns here, or a row/column of zero using elementary operations. But I don't see what I should do?

Comment: Are you sure it's equal to zero? In the 2x2 case, you get $n^2-2n$

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt No, you get $2^2 - 2*2$, since $n = 2$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, ignore me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Add all other rows to the first row. What row you'll obtain after that?

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalue of the $n \times n$ matrix in which every entry is $1$ is $n$ (of multiplicity $1$) and $0$ (of multiplicity $n-1$). [Proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217521/what-are-the-eigenvalues-of-matrix-that-have-all-elements-equal-1)

So, for such a matrix $A$, we have $\det(A - \lambda I_n) = 0$, and $\lambda = n$.

Comment: Haven't really studied eigenvalues yet properly, but good to know anyways.

Comment: How can a matrix full of ones not have 0 as an eigenvalue? Its rank is 1.

Comment: @anderstood It's a typo I think, 1 should say 0 since $\det(A - \lambda I_n) = x^n - nx^{n-1}$.