# Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ the matrix defined Calulate $det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ the matrix defined by:

$$a_{ij}=\begin{eqnarray}n+1 &&&&&&&&\text{if $i=j$}\\
1 &&&&&&&&\text{if $i\not=j$}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Calulate $\det(A)$

**My work:**

By definition $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
n+1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&1\\
1&&n+1&&1&&1&&...&&1\\
1&&1&&n+1&&1&&...&&1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Apply elemental operation by rows, we have:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
n+1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&1\\
1&&n+1&&1&&1&&...&&1\\
1&&1&&n+1&&1&&...&&1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1
\end{pmatrix}\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
1&&n+1&&1&&1&&...&&1\\
1&&1&&n+1&&1&&...&&1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
n+1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&1
\end{pmatrix}\\\\
\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
0&&n&&0&&0&&...&&-n\\
0&&0&&n&&0&&...&&-n\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
n&&0&&0&&0&&...&&-n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
0&&n&&0&&0&&...&&-n\\
0&&0&&n&&0&&...&&-n\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0&&-n&&-n&&-n&&...&&-n^2-2n
\end{pmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
0&&n&&0&&0&&...&&-n\\
0&&0&&n&&0&&...&&-n\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0&&0&&-n&&-n&&...&&-n^2-3n
\end{pmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
0&&n&&0&&0&&...&&-n\\
0&&0&&n&&0&&...&&-n\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0&&0&&0&&-n&&...&&-n^2-4n
\end{pmatrix}
\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
0&&n&&0&&0&&...&&-n\\
0&&0&&n&&0&&...&&-n\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0&&0&&0&&0&&...&&n^2-n^n
\end{pmatrix}=B
$$

Then, 
$\det(A)=-\det(B)=-\det\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1&&1&&1&&...&&n+1\\
0&&n&&0&&0&&...&&-n\\
0&&0&&n&&0&&...&&-n\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
0&&0&&0&&0&&...&&n^2-n^n
\end{pmatrix}=-n^{n-1}+n^n$

I have a little doubt in the $n\times n$ element, I think is a little different. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A=nI_n+vv^T$, where $v=(1,\dots,1)^T$. Using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), we have
$$ \det(nI_n+vv^T)=\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}v^Tv\Big)\det(nI_n)=2n^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing $A=nI_n+U$, where $U$ is the matrix with all elements equal to one, the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are solutions to the characteristic polynomial $\det(U-(\lambda-n)I_n)=\det(U-\lambda'I_n)$, where $\lambda'=\lambda-n$. In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217521/what-are-the-eigenvalues-of-matrix-that-have-all-elements-equal-1) was shown that $U$ has all eigenvalues $\lambda'$ equal to $0$, except for one that is equal to $n$. Then $A$ has all eigenvalues $\lambda$ equal to $n$, except for one that is equal to $2n$.  As the determinant is the product of eigenvalues, $\det(A)=n^{n-1}\cdot 2n=2n^n$.